# Grails-The different dependence Injection ways in grails

Tags: grails, service, inject

What's the difference of different way to inject dependence in grails:

1. ABCService abcService
2. def        abcService
3. @Autowired
   ABCService ABCService

Comment: The `def` form was always recommended in earlier versions of Grails because of the way development-time reloading operated by replacing a classloader - if you gave an explicit type you'd end up with "X cannot be cast to X" errors when things got reloaded.  I believe the agent-based reloader in more recent Grails does a better job of this, but old habits die hard (and more to the point, extensive libraries of example code and documentation from the Grails 1.x days are still out there and getting copied by new users).

Comment: Would you please explain what is "agent-based reloader " ?

Comment: Recent versions of grails use https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded, a Java agent that allows it to swap in modified bytecode at runtime without having to replace the entire classloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Expected type is specified, if service with name `abcService` (or other Spring bean with such name) will have different `class`, then you'll get `ClassCastException` here
2. Just any bean with name `abcService`
3. Spring annotation, it's optional. But if you've marked a field but Grails/Spring cannot find such bean it will throw `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` (previous two will get `null` if it doesn't exists) `@Autowired` could be combined with `def` type also

Basically Grails services are standard Spring beans, Grails just follows [`convention over configuration`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) that for every class in `services` dir it will create a bean with name `abcService` that could be autowired into other beans. All other job is done by Spring. See also docs for [Spring and Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html)